# Scene Builder 2.0 can't load stylesheet from resources/classpath

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

My FXML file has an attribute `stylesheets="styles/Styles.css"` specified on the root node. This works fine when the program is launched. However, in Scene Builder 2 the css doesn't load, the console prints `WARNING: Resource "styles/Styles.css" not found.`, the Properties panel doesn't work, and the console further prints stack traces. If the stylesheets attribute is specified with an absolute `file:` url, then SB works, but I need the url to point to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

In my case is stylesheet defined like this inside of root element:

```
    <stylesheets>
       <URL value="@css/base.css" />
    </stylesheets>
```

In this notation it probable means, that file is searched for relatively from FXML file position.

But you must specify location of loaded FXML file in runtime.

```
   // file = String with FXML file path, loader = FXMLLoader
   URL resource = getClass().getResource(file);
   loader.setLocation(resource);
```

I hope, it will help you...

Btw Scene Builder 2.0 is still Early Access version, so there might be some problem too...